# Menorah lighting at work and saying shechechiyanu

Tags: chanuka

According to European/Ashkenazi customs, if one is asked to light the menorah at work approximately 10 minutes after sunset, Is it a problem:

1. to say the blessings at work
2. to say the blessings again at home with ones wife and kids, including the shechechiyanu blessing

Comment: I think your question is asked [elsewhere](/q/33589) and answered already. If your question remains after reading the question there, then please [edit] it to distinguish it from that one so it can be reopened.