# Lit the menorah at my mother's home, then again at my home. Which brachot are said?

Tags: halacha, blessing, chanuka, menora-chanukia

> Note:  This is related to
>   [Lighting the menora in shul and at home. How many brochos need be said?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/lighting-the-menora-in-shul-and-at-home-how-many-brochos-need-be-said),
>   except that in that case one of the occasions involved a *minyan*, and
>   the explanation offered in the accepted answer there seems to depend
>   on that fact ("the reasoning is that each new minyan is a new
>   obligation, even if everyone in the minyan already lit individually").
>   Also related is
>   [Menorah lighting at work and saying shechechiyanu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65998/menorah-lighting-at-work-and-saying-shechechiyanu),
>   but that question is currently on hold.

Yesterday evening, the first night of Chanukah, my family visited my mother's home, and we all (myself, my wife, and our children) lit the *chanukiyah* at her house.  To be more precise, my mother lit the candles, but we all sang the b'rachot in unison together.

Later that evening when we returned home we lit our own *menorah*.  Naturally the question arose:  Should we recite *shehecheyanu*?  What about the other brachot?

On reflection, it seems a more fundamental question is:  Is it appropriate to recite b'rachot communally, when only one person is actually performing the *mitzvah*?  This is how my family has done it since I was a little kid, but that of course doesn't mean it's halachically proper.

Comment: In general, only the person doing the Maaseh Mitzvah (the Mitzva action itself) says the blessing 'Asher Kiddeshanu...' whether or not that person is fulfilling any command (eg. putting a Mezuza on someone else's house).

Comment: @DoubleAA What about She'asah Nissim?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46444&st=&pgnum=154&hilite=

Comment: @GershonGold Could you provide an English translation or at least a synopsis of that source?

Comment: @mweiss Gershon linked to the *Nit'ei Gavriel* (Rabbi Gavriel Zinner), who cited the Ritva (*Shabbos* 23a) and *P'ri Chadash* (OC 676) regarding whether or not to recite *She'asah Nissim* (and *Shehechiyanu* on the first night, but specifically excluding the first blessing on performing the mitzva itself) in various cases involving observing someone in a different household lighting. *Shulchan 'Aruch* (OC 676:3) rules that one should only do this when one will not be lighting that night, nor will anyone light at home for him, nor will he pay for a share in someone else's candle lighting.